# Remove unnecessary JS files to optimize Total Blocking Time

Tags: performance

I need to improve the performance of a site and check it with [Carbon Neutral Website](https://carbonneutralwebsite.org/calculate). One of the most difficult thing I find is to remove "Total Blocking Time", the problem is that Drupal includes a lot of files that really aren't used in the web design.

I would like to be able to search and remove the files that aren't really used. Is it a way how to remove them? (maybe with libraries-override). Or what is the recommended way to optimice a Drupal site?

PD: I know about "Aggregate JavaScript files", however, the result shows a lot of problems. So I prefer to remove unnecessary files.

[image: Carbon Recommendations]

```
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/underscore/underscore-min.js?v=1.13.6"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/polyfills/object.assign.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/polyfills/nodelist.foreach.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/css-escape/css.escape.js?v=1.5.1"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/es6-promise/es6-promise.auto.min.js?v=4.2.8"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery-once/jquery.once.min.js?v=2.2.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/version-min.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/data-min.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/disable-selection-min.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/focusable-min.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/form-min.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/ie-min.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/jquery-patch-min.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/keycode-min.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/plugin-min.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/safe-active-element-min.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/safe-blur-min.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/scroll-parent-min.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/unique-id-min.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/widget-min.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete-min.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/labels-min.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/widgets/menu-min.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/tabbable/index.umd.min.js?v=5.3.3"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/autocomplete.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/libraries/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?sacm5y"></script>
<script src="/themes/contrib/bootstrap/js/drupal.bootstrap.js?sacm5y"></script>
<script src="/themes/contrib/bootstrap/js/attributes.js?sacm5y"></script>
<script src="/themes/contrib/bootstrap/js/theme.js?sacm5y"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/jquery.once.bc.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/themes/contrib/bootstrap/js/popover.js?sacm5y"></script>
<script src="/themes/contrib/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js?sacm5y"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/debounce.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/form.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/themes/contrib/bootstrap/js/misc/form.js?sacm5y"></script>
<script src="/modules/contrib/webform/js/webform.behaviors.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/states.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/themes/contrib/bootstrap/js/misc/states.js?sacm5y"></script>
<script src="/modules/contrib/webform/js/webform.states.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/modules/contrib/webform/js/webform.form.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/modules/contrib/webform/js/webform.element.details.save.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/announce.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/modules/contrib/webform/js/webform.element.details.toggle.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/progress.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/themes/contrib/bootstrap/js/misc/progress.js?sacm5y"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/loadjs/loadjs.min.js?v=4.2.0"></script>
<script src="/core/modules/responsive_image/js/responsive_image.ajax.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/ajax.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/themes/contrib/bootstrap/js/misc/ajax.js?sacm5y"></script>
<script src="/modules/contrib/webform/js/webform.scroll.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/modules/contrib/webform/js/webform.ajax.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/modules/contrib/webform/js/webform.element.message.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery-form/jquery.form.min.js?v=4.3.0"></script>
<script src="/modules/contrib/webform/js/webform.element.select.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/modules/custom/zoom_messenger/js/scriptZoom.js?v=1"></script>
<script src="/libraries/dompurify/dist/purify.min.js?sacm5y"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/jquery.tabbable.shim.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/position.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/modules/contrib/search_autocomplete/js/jquery.autocomplete.js?v=9.5.3"></script>
<script src="/themes/contrib/bootstrap/js/misc/autocomplete.js?sacm5y"></script>
```

Comment: See the answer on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/291948/why-is-libraries-override-not-removing-assets for examples

Comment: For many years this has been via https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg

Comment: Also searching for "Drupal lighthouse" will give you a lot of info.  Lighthouse is a far more popular set of metrics from Google, and blocking time is one of the metrics.

Comment: This topic is so wide it can't be easily answered with a single reply. There's lot of things to cover and dive in into so called "Core Web Vitals". As a good start I encourage to take a look at web.dev, understand topics like lighthouse and Google Page Insights (differences between tools), LCP, FCP, CLS, CrUX. At web.dev there's lot of examples on how to start working with the issues and understand the problem. This can't be fixed with just an extra module installation and config. It's a new chapter to discover and lot of new things to learn. It can take long time to get a decent result.

Answer (score -2):

Well your question isn't clear enough.

when you say "PD: I know about "Aggregate JavaScript files", however, the result shows a lot of problems. So I prefer to remove unnecessary files."

Do you mean you have design problems? (can you give an example?), if so it means you need to investigate why that happens. most probably its an issue with libraries priorities and dependancies. so fixing that is recommended.

you could always prevent a library from loading by using `libraries-override:` but that always comes at a cost of testing.

Finally you could also play around with processing your JS files and creating bundles outside of Drupal and using these files.